# Intellij outputs wierd characters for keys that are should not output anything

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij keeps making my life difficult. I decided to go to the bottom with it today and create a new keyboard mapping for mac using the program ukulele.

By default, Mac will output all kinds of weird characters when you hold down the option key. Now, since I never use any of those, I prefer to use them for shortcuts and using ukelele you can create a new keyboard layout. The program works fine. It is good.

Now, shortcuts are not filled on the keyboard, and in the learning phase, you will try some that are not working, or assigned.

When this happens, Intellij outputs weird characters instead. Characters such as     for instance for the combo option + r. Same for e, t and so on.

This does not occur in chrome, the terminal, TextEdit or any other program.

Intellij seems to realize the combo does not result in anything and decides to put out the same character for all those keys.

As you see in the picture below from the macOS build-in keyboard viewer, the keys are not mapped (option being held down) at all.

[image]

Note, that only Intellij so far outputs these characters.

[image]

Comment: Is there any change if you add `com.jetbrains.use.old.keyevent.processing=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, it disappeared. Everything new seems to be leading to worse than before functionality. All three posts I posted deals with new things. Even search.everywhere thing is sluggish in search, it is almost as if you are searching on the web.

Comment: However, I just also noticed that the keys stop responding to key mappings, meaning I can not assign them to a shortcut. This was not a problem with the new keyevent processing.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235741